# Remove some part from the text using regex in python3.x

Tags: regex, python-3.x, replace

I need to remove the part until `:` from all the lines ( excluding `:` appearing in datetime format) given as below. Is there a way to pick the length and replace it with " ".

a.txt

```
Mon Sep 17 04:01:35 2018 abc.mnba:15885: afhoashfodcasnc.
Mon Sep 17 04:01:35 2018 abc.mnba:16199: inancaaldajijeijiodncna
Mon Sep 17 04:01:35 2018 abc:9: iunancn andjcadjjacnn noancoan
Mon Sep 17 04:01:35 2018 abc: abc = {
          'uf' => '',
          'uft' => 'afbcjbja',
          'ufd' => 'saflkacklmsakcmk',
          'ufc' => 'ubakcb'
        };
```

*Expected Solution*

```
afhoashfodcasnc.
inancaaldajijeijiodncna
iunancn andjcadjjacnn noancoan
$abc = {
          'uf' => '',
          'uft' => 'afbcjbja',
          'ufd' => 'saflkacklmsakcmk',
          'ufc' => 'ubakcb'
        };
askpfmkasmkvmksamvmk
Kdriver: jafnajncjjanjnnfjnjajjf 
fkcjkackkakkafjkajkfjdka
I hcjfdajnfcjnajncjjanjnjnjndjnfjcnjn
I afkjakcnakkdfjncnalldkfkdafkccnnlkn 

kdfjkackanjdnfjajsfdcjcnjnjanjnfcaksfaljscll
fajncjnjanjdnfjnajsdnfjcnjakncjajnfjajdfjanjncjnjnja
ijfiandfnanejfdcijiandnajfnejdfhncncjnjanjnedfncjanncfjanjcnj
akmfkcmkmakmkdmfekmfkmkckmakmdkmfkmkamdfcammdckmckcmkckdkal ladmflmalcml
```

*My Solution*

```
import re

with open("a.txt", 'r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        line = re.sub(r"^.{20}", "", lines)
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern has to get a little more complicated than your suggestion. I have tested this one and it seems to get your expectedd result:

```
import re

with open("a.txt", 'r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        if ":" in lines:
            line = re.findall(r":\s?\D.+$", lines)[0][1:].strip()
        else:
            line = lines
        print(line)
```

This prints out the following result

```
afhoashfodcasnc.
inancaaldajijeijiodncna
iunancn andjcadjjacnn noancoan
$abc = {
          'uf' => '',
          'uft' => 'afbcjbja',
          'ufd' => 'saflkacklmsakcmk',
          'ufc' => 'ubakcb'
        };
askpfmkasmkvmksamvmk
Kdriver: jafnajncjjanjnnfjnjajjf 
fkcjkackkakkafjkajkfjdka
I hcjfdajnfcjnajncjjanjnjnjndjnfjcnjn
I afkjakcnakkdfjncnalldkfkdafkccnnlkn 

kdfjkackanjdnfjajsfdcjcnjnjanjnfcaksfaljscll
fajncjnjanjdnfjnajsdnfjcnjakncjajnfjajdfjanjncjnjnja
ijfiandfnanejfdcijiandnajfnejdfhncncjnjanjnedfncjanncfjanjcnj
akmfkcmkmakmkdmfekmfkmkckmakmdkmfkmkamdfcammdckmckcmkckdkal ladmflmalcml
```

Comment: Thanks John!. i know it requires some complicated regex pattern. But I am still naive to regex that's why it was challenge for me.

Comment: I am getting` IndexError: list index out of range` while running this code.

Comment: And only first three lines I am getting as a result.

Comment: I made a small change in my original post. I have just tested it and it works. Try it out

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
import re

with open("a.txt", 'r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        line = re.sub(r".*:", "", lines)
        print(line)
```

Note that it removes *Kdriver:* as well.